# Restart windows service on LAN machine

Tags: windows-7, services, remote, reboot, windows-services

I got administrative rights on the target machine, all the credentials, fully trusted network without firewall and antivirus software. I got windows 8 on the target machine and windows 7 on calling one.

- I need to restart a windows service by its name. I have this name.

I got the IP address of that machine. I have the simple shell. I could use the powershell however.

Still I cannot find on the internet the fine shell command to do this. Everything I find says either it is impossble or providing not working piece of code.

**Update:**
Both computers are located ta my home and does not belong to domain. They only share teh same workgroup.

**Update:**

Just created a powershell script:

```
$password = convertto-securestring -string 'pwd_string' -asplaintext -force
$credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "AF", $password
$service = gwmi win32_service -computername "AgentFire" -filter "name='Sharedaccess'" -credential $credential
$service.stopservice()
Start-Sleep -s 3
$service.startservice()
```

**gwmi** says access denied, though credentials are valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could manage to do this is:

```
PsExec.exe \\192.168.0.106 -u 123 -p 123 -d shutdown /f /s /t 0
```

1. External tool from **SysInternals**.
2. User-password combo on the target PC
3. Shutdown.exe shell command.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
sc \\SERVER [start|stop|restart] ServiceName
```

Works from Windows 8 to Server 2012.

Comment: [SC] StartService: OpenService FAILED 5: access denied.

Comment: How to, at first, logon to the remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm wrong, please let me know.

According to [this site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736564%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) you should be able to use the `net [start/stop] [servicename]` command to start or stop a service by its name. If you just need to kill a process, you could just get the PID by using `tasklist` and `taskkill` with the appropriate flags.

Comment: This does not work when I run it on one machine to restart a service on another machine.

Comment: I have both, simple and power.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: With `net [start/stop] [servicename]` there is no error as well as any attempt. The command you provided does not allow to specify the remote machine name. Or I cannot find where this can be specified.

Comment: You said you had a shell into the second computer. If you had this you wouldn't need to specify the machine name.

Comment: I meant I have both generic windows shell and power shell. I cant have shell logon into target computer. I'd like to know how to do that.